# CSS - Font for a web based editor

Tags: css, fonts

I'm building a web based code editor. I'm currently using

```
font-family : "Courier New", Courier, monospace
```

as the rule for both line numbers and the source code.

- Does it work on every OS?
- Is there a better font than Courier new that's both targeted towards source code and installed in majority of computers?

Comment: Check out consolas.http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17879

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Taken from Stack Overflow's CSS:

```
code {
    font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif;
}
```

You can be sure it's been tested :)

Answer (score 3):

The Bootstrap default is:

```
code {
   font-family: Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
}
```